# How can you determine how long a php file was running for before it was terminated?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

We have a long running php file that can be started and killed whenever a sys admin wants.

How do I determine how long the php file was run each time is was run?

I wasn't able to see anything in

```
cat /var/log/message | grep filename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to make your script capture the termination signal (`SIGTERM`/`SIGINT`) and then calculate and save (or display) the elapsed time before exiting. Unless there are errors, it is unlikely that the script will show up in any logs (especailly if you are running it from CLI). Something like the following should do:

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
declare(ticks = 1);

pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, "signal_handler");
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, "signal_handler");

function signal_handler($signal) {
    global $time_start;
    switch($signal) {
        case SIGTERM:
        case SIGINT:
            file_put_contents("runtime.txt", microtime(true) - $time_start);
            exit;
    }
}

//your script functions go here

?>
```

As long as you don't terminate your script will `SIGKILL`, the above should work fine (e.g. if you terminate with `Ctrl+C`, `kill`, or even `killall`; only `kill -9` will not let the script capture the signal). [Tested and working on RHEL/CentOS with PHP-5.3.8]